# How can I obtain a selected value from an HTML element and pass the value to a function call,

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an app that is supposed to calculate the BMI of a user based on their `weight`, `height` and `country`.

So in my `letsCalculateBMI` arrow function, I need to get it to obtain the selected value from the `select` element and inside the same `letsCalculateBMI` function pass that value to a `getSelectedUser` function call, which should return the user object for the selected value. This user object should be assigned to a user variable.

Summarily what this `letsCalculateBMI` function should achieve is to claculate the user's BMI. It should do this by calling `computeBMI` and passing it `user`. It then sets the return value from invoking `computeBMI` to a `bmi` variable, which is finally set as the text content of the `PARAGRAPH` within the #outcome DIV

Here's a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3UKUV01YLKW)

index.js

```
const users = [];

      const countriesWithLowerBmi = ["Chad", "Sierra Leone", "Mali", "Gambia", "Uganda", "Ghana", "Senegal", "Somalia", "Ivory Coast", "Isreal"];      

      const featToMeter = 0.3048;

      const bmiCountryRatio = 0.82;

      const computeBMI = ({weight, height, country}) => {
        const heightInMeters = height * featToMeter;
        let BMI = weight / (heightInMeters^2);

       if (countriesWithLowerBmi.includes(country)) 
         BMI *= bmiCountryRatio;

       return Math.round(BMI, 2);
      };

      const getSelectedUser = (userId) => {
        return users.find(({id}) => id === userId);
      };


      const letsCalculateBMI = () => {

        const value = document.querySelector('.select-text').value;
        const user =getSelectedUser(target.value);      

        const bmi = computeBMI(user);

        document.querySelector('.bmi-text').innerHTML = bmi
      };

      const powerupTheUI = () => {
        const button = document.querySelector('#oracle');

        const select = document.querySelector('.select-text');

        select.addEventListener('change', displaySelectedUser);

        button.addEventListener('click',letsCalculateBMI);
      };
```

index.html

```
<div class="select">
      <select class="select-text">
        <option disabled selected>Select User</option>        
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="user-photo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="Placeholder" >
    </div>

    <div class="details mdc-elevation--z3">
      <p>
        <span class="prop" data-age>Age :</span>
        <span class="value" data-age-value>23 years</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="prop" data-height>Height :</span>
        <span class="value" data-height-value>169cm</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="prop" data-weight>Weight :</span>
        <span class="value" data-weight-value>68kg</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="prop" data-gender>Gender :</span>
        <span class="value" data-gender-value>Female</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="prop" data-country>Country :</span>
        <span class="value" data-country-value>Nigerian</span>
      </p>
    </div>

    <button id="oracle" class="mdc-button">Calculate BMI</button>
    <div id="outcome">
      <h5 class="mdc-typography--headline5" >
        BMI
      </h5>
      <p></p> //This is the P element      
    </div>
```

Comment: Suggestion: Remove all code that is not related to the problem. Try to create a very simple HTML/JS combination that shows your problem. Please don't copy paste an entire section of code. That will make others more willing to help since right now it requires a lot of reading and it's hard to tell what your actual question is.

Comment: Its called a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The code you presented is not a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it's hard to build on it, but the gist is basically that for `<input>`, `<select>` and other form elements, you can access their value with the `.value` property. Note that the value is always a string, so for numbers you have to convert it first so as to avoid bugs (for example by adding a `+` in front of the string value).

Once you get the values of the country, the weight and the height, it's simple JS-side programming. Here's a quick BMI calculator:

```js
const computeBMI = () => {
  let country = document.querySelector('#country').value;
  let weight = +document.querySelector('#weight').value;
  let height = +document.querySelector('#height').value;
  let bmi = weight / (height^2);
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = bmi;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Country:
  <select id="country">
    <option value="usa">USA</option>
    <option value="other">Rest of the world</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  Weight:
  <input id="weight" type="number" value="0">
  (in kg)
</p>
<p>
  Height:
  <input id="height" type="number" value="0">
  (in m)
</p>
<p>
  Your BMI is <span id="result">(not computed yet)</span>
  <button onclick="computeBMI()">Compute BMI</button>
</p>
```

Comment: I just added a link. I will prefer to have the logic inside `letsCalculateBMI`

Answer (score 0):

In your letsCalculateBMI function, the getSelectedUser function should only receive value as an argument (not target.value).